# How to connect a TVS to protect the data lines in a USB device port?

Tags: usb, ftdi

TVS is a good practice to protect USB ports.  A USB (at least 2.0) connection has the power path supplied with a 5 V source (Vbus=5V0) at the host side and the data path supplied with a 3.3 V sources (3V3) at both ends of the connection.

A TVS protecting the data lines (D+, D-), is connected like the following:

[image]

**Should it be connected to 5V0 (Vbus) or 3V3?**  Why so?  Arguments?  References?

(This is especially interesting in the case of FTDI and similar ICs whose transceiver logic is supplied from the internal 3.3 V LDO.)

Comment: What's the clamping voltage of the TVS?

Comment: @MattYoung I think the TVS clamping voltage is a second question and depends on the connection scheme being selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This style of TVS is intended to be either connected to a power rail, or to be connected to ground only. In that second mode, a positive transient pulse will go through the top-side diode, then break down the TVS diode around 6V, clamping to ground through that device.

Here is [a datasheet from Semtech](http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/rclamp0554s.pdf) that describes how to use one of their parts like this. See Figure 4 on page 7.

tl;dr, they connect the common cathode to \$V_{bus}\$, which is +5V.

This additionally serves as ESD protection for \$V_{bus}\$.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking, hooking the TVS to 3.3V should give lower (better) level of signal clamping, by 1.7V. However, practically it might be harder to route a 3.3V rail in near vicinity of USB connector. More, when ESD (or EFT) strikes the wires, the peak signal will still be at 10-15V, due to finite dynamic impedance of diodes. So the 10%-15% gain may not be worth troubles of wasting PCB space.